# tkinter mostrar datos en pantalla y obtener datos de un Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests, beautifulsoup, hash

Hola esta es mi primera pregunta resulta que puedo hacer que este código me imprima el Hash md5 por consola pero no lo puedo hacer gráficamente quisiera que por favor Alguien me arreglar el código de manera explicativa para poder entender de una vez esta librería de tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

root=Tk()
root.title("prueva")
root.geometry("800x600")


search_kw = Entry(root)
search_kw.pack()

def md5():
    try:
        
        url = "https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=5da2297bad6924526e48e00dbfc3c27a"
      
        HEADER = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"}

        page = requests.get(url, headers = HEADER)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        #md5 = soup.find_all('em', class_='long-content string')
        md5 = soup.find('em', {"class":"long-content string"})

        md5hash = md5.text
        #print('El desengriptado del hash MD5 ',search_kw +' es el siguente')
        
        print(md5hash)

    except AttributeError:
        print("intento 2 fallido")


boton1=Button(root, text="Enviar", command=md5)
boton1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

OJO: está script lo que hace es desencriptar HASH en formato md5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

root=Tk()
root.title("prueva")
root.geometry("800x600")

texto=StringVar()
```

lo último que hice es declarar una variable en formato cadena

```
search_kw = Entry(root,text=texto)
```

ahora esa variable se la asigno al entry

```
search_kw.pack()

def md5():
    try:
        
        url = "https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=5da2297bad6924526e48e00dbfc3c27a"
      
        HEADER = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"}

        page = requests.get(url, headers = HEADER)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        #md5 = soup.find_all('em', class_='long-content string')
        md5 = soup.find('em', {"class":"long-content string"})

        md5hash = md5.text
        #print('El desengriptado del hash MD5 ',search_kw +' es el siguente')
        texto.set(md5hash)
```

por último le asigno a la variable lo que quiero mostrar

```
      print(md5hash)

    except AttributeError:
        print("intento 2 fallido")


boton1=Button(root, text="Enviar", command=md5)
boton1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

el resto es todo igual.
Como comentario te diré que lo mejor es hacer

```
import tkinter as tk
```

y después usarlo así por ejemplo:

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

y así para los otros elementos que componen la biblioteca.